# A nonnegative random variable has zero expectation if and only if it is zero almost surely

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $Y$ be a non-negative random variable. Prove that $E(Y) = 0$ if and only if $P(Y=0)=1$.

My understanding is that while you can prove it for discrete $Y$, the result is true for all $Y$.

Comment: What is the meaning of $P(Y=0) = 1$ for non-discrete $Y$?

Comment: For a non-discrete random variable isn't $ P (Y=c)=0$ where c can be zero or anyother value $ Y $ can take on?

Comment: @nishrito I don't really know. You're asking the same question I am. I'm wondering if the question itself is incorrect.

Comment: If $Y$ is non-discrete but positive, we can say $P(Y = 0) = 1$ iff $P(Y < \epsilon) = 1$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 I think you intended $P(|Y|<\epsilon)=1$ but I would still describe this as a discrete random variable (its support is a finite or countably infinite number of points)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If $Y$ is a non-negative random variable defined on a probability space $\Omega$ and

$$E(Y) = \int_{\Omega} Y dP=0$$

then $Y = 0$ almost surely and $P(\{\omega \in \Omega: Y(\omega)=0\})=1$.

Proof: For any $m \in \mathbf{N}$, let

$$E_m = \{\omega \in \Omega:Y(\omega) > 1/m\}$$

then, since $Y$ is non-negative, we have $Y = Y1_{\Omega} \geq Y 1_{E_m}$ and then

$$0 = \int_{\Omega} Y dP \geq \int_{E_m} Y dP\geq \frac1{m}P(E_m) \geq 0,$$

and $P(E_m) = 0$.

So

$$0 \leq P(\{\omega \in \Omega:Y(\omega) \neq 0\})= P\left(\bigcup E_m\right) = \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}P(E_m)=0$$

Hence

$$P(\{\omega \in \Omega:Y(\omega) \neq 0\})=0 \implies P(\{\omega \in \Omega:Y(\omega) = 0\})=1 $$ QED

Conversely, if $Y=0$ a.s. then $E(Y) = \int Y dP = 0$

Comment: Does "Y = 0 almost surely" mean the same as "Y approaches 0 in the limit"? Thanks.

Comment: It means $Y = 0$ except on a negligible set of probability measure $0$.

Comment: So the probability of the event $(Y=0)$ is $1$.

Comment: But how do you reconcile that to the definition of a continuous random variable which requires that $P(Y = c)=0$ at any single point?

Comment: The random variable $Y$ is a measurable function on the probability space, $Y:\Omega \rightarrow [0,\infty)$. Yes -- at a single point $P(Y(\omega_0)=c)=0$. But $(Y=0)$ is an event: $(Y=0):=\{\omega:Y(\omega)=0\}.$ not a singleton.

Comment: OK. That clarifies things. Thanks!

Comment: Its the set of all outcomes where takes the value $0$ and has non-zero measure.  Analagous to if the Lebesgue integral of a non-negative function is zero -- the function has to be zero everywhere except possibly at some points that are in a "small" set of measure zero.

Comment: I do not understand why the converse is "obvious", i.e. why does $Y=0$ a.s. implies that $E(Y)=0$.

Comment: @MichaelBaudin: As in the general theory of integration of functions defined on a measure space, the expected value (integral) of a nonnegative random variable $Y$ is defined as $E(Y) = \int_\Omega Y \, dP = \sup_{\varphi \leqslant Y} \int_\Omega \varphi \, dP$ where the supremum is taken over integrals of all simple random variables dominated by $Y$.  A simple random variable has a finite number of distinct values on disjoint events, i.e., $\varphi(\omega) = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \mathbf{1}_{A_j}(\omega)$ and $\int_\Omega \varphi \, dP = \sum_{j=1}^n a_jP(A_j)$.

Comment: Now if $Y=0$ a.s., then if $0 \leqslant \varphi \leqslant Y$ you should be able to show easily that $\int_\Omega \varphi \, dP = 0$ for any such $\varphi$ and the supremum of integrals is also zero.  Let $E = \{\omega \, | \, Y(\omega) \neq 0\}$ and since $P(E) = 0$, show $\int_\Omega \varphi \, dP = \int_{\Omega \setminus E} \varphi \, dP + \int_E \varphi \, dP = 0$.

Comment: do we need to assume any convention like $\infty \times 0 = 0$ ? like $Y = \infty$ on a set of probability zero or something

Comment: @BCLC: First if $Y = \infty$ on any subset with positive measure, then we can't fulfill the hypothesis $E(Y) = 0$ for the forward implication.  Are you asking if $\int_{E} Y \, dP  = 0$ when $Y= \infty$ and $P(E) =0$?  That is true by definition of the integral: 
 For positive part $\int_E Y^+ \, dP$ is the supremum of integrals over simple functions $\varphi \leqslant Y^+$ and since $P(E) = 0$ we have $\int_E \varphi = 0$. Similarly for $Y^-$.

Comment: right thanks. been awhile since i've done this

Comment: wait maybe for the direction where $E Y = 0$ is the conclusion might we need to assume?

Answer (score 4):

Sufficiency is obvious. For necessity, assume for contradiction that $E[Y] = 0$ and $P(Y > 0) = c > 0$. From total expectation, we have:

$$
0 = E[Y] \ge P(Y>0)E[Y\mid Y >0] = cE[Y \mid Y>0] > 0.
$$

Comment: nice. i knew there had to be some way to do this without continuity of measure/probability.