# Does the expectation of square difference of two random variables being zero mean that random variables are equal?

Tags: probability

What I have got is the following:

Given: $E[(X-Y)^2]=0 \Rightarrow X=Y \ where \ X,Y\in\mathbb{R}$

$$
E[(X-Y)^2]=0 \Rightarrow Var(X-Y)+E^2[X-Y]=0
$$
Since both terms are non-negative:
$$
E^2[X-Y]\geq0 \ , \ Var(X-Y)\geq0 \\
Var(X-Y) =0, E[X]=E[Y]
$$

And a random variable with zero variance is a constant.
$$
X-Y = c, E[c]=0 \Rightarrow c=0 \Rightarrow X=Y
$$

Is there anything wrong with the statement?

Edit:  where $c$ is a constant.

Comment: $\mathsf{E}[(X-Y)^2]=0$ implies that $X-Y=0$ a.s. directly.

Comment: care to elaborate?

Comment: A nonnegative r.v. with zero mean can't be positive with positive probability, so must be almost surely $0$. Your last statement looks wrong though.

Comment: so the statement is correct, I just made it too complicated, thx.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897876/a-nonnegative-random-variable-has-zero-expectation-if-and-only-if-it-is-zero-alm

Comment: @nejimban my last statement is since I showed $X-Y$ is a constant (0 variance) and I have shown that $E[X-Y]=0$, therefore, $X-Y=0$ because the expectation of a constant is the constant.

Answer (score 1):

By the property of non-degeneracy, we have
$$\operatorname{E}\left[(X-Y)^2\right]=0\implies (X-Y)^2\overset{a\ s}=0$$
Now we can proceed as follows
$$\begin{aligned}(X-Y)^2&\overset{a\ s}=0\\
X-Y&\overset{a\ s}=0\\
X&\overset{a\ s}=Y\end{aligned}$$
Note that $X\overset{a\ s}=Y$ means that $X$ and $Y$ are equal [almost surely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely), if and only if, the probability that $X$ and $Y$ are different is zero.

Comment: when you write "By the property of non-degeneracy"
you mean since,  nonnegative r.v. with zero mean can't be positive with positive probability, so must be almost surely 0?

if so I think it is more informative to add that.