# Prove conditional expectation as minimization of squared error

Tags: probability, statistics, optimization, conditional-probability

I'm a bit confused about the universality of this statement:

Suppose we have real-valued random variables $Y,X$, and differentiable function $f(X)$ (perhaps some model). Do not assume that $f(X)$ is convex.

$$ \mathbb{E}[Y \mid X] = \text{argmin}_f \mathbb{E}[(Y - f(X))^2] $$

Is this always true? And if so, why? Most of these proofs rely on reducing the statement above to (e.g., [here](https://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2019/10/04/expectation-median-opt/)):

$$ \text{argmin}_f \mathbb{E}[(\mathbb{E}[Y] - f(X))^2]$$

Then they take the derivative to compute the minimum to show the result, but this would require $f(x)$ to be convex, so would the above statement always hold?

Comment: At which point do they take a derivative in the proof that you linked? They add/subtract $E[Y|X]$ and show the cross term goes to zero

Comment: They have a note about convexity in the first proof and use it to show that we choose $a = \mathbb{E}[X]$

Comment: convexity of the function $x \mapsto x^2$, not convexity of the function $f$ as you claim in your question

Comment: Ah ok, this makes sense then

Comment: That's the first proof. In the second they use that ${\cal G}\ni g\mapsto \mathbb E[(\mathbb E[Y|X]-g(X))^2]$ is a convex functional that is minimized (obviously) at $g^*(X)=\mathbb E[Y|X]$. A nice reference BTW.

Comment: Hmm, actually now I that I look at it again, I don't seem to understand why that function would necessarily be convex. as it is a function of $g(X)$. Not too sure why he mentioned convexity here

Comment: That was in fact a good observation.

Comment: It doesn't have to be necessarily convex right?

Comment: Nope (as the accepted answer also says). Once we know that we only have to minimize $\mathbb E[(\mathbb E[Y|X]-g(X))^2]$ it becomes completely trivial. I find it nonetheless  interesting in itself that the functional is convex in $g$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to take derivatives or invoke convexity. Having established that
$$
E\left[ (Y-f(X))^2\right]=E\left[(Y-E(Y\mid X))\right]^2+E\left[(E(Y\mid X)-f(X))^2\right]=a+b,\tag{$\ast$}
$$
we observe the LHS of $(\ast)$ is minimized when $b$ is minimized. Since $b$ is the expectation of a non-negative random variable, it is clear that $b\ge0$. But taking $\hat f(X):=E(Y\mid X)$ leads to $b=0$, hence $\hat f(X)$ is a choice for $f(X)$ that minimizes the LHS.

Now if also $h(X)$ minimizes the LHS of $(\ast)$, then we must have
$$E\left[(E(Y\mid X)-h(X))^2\right]=0$$ as well. But $(E(Y\mid X)-h(X))^2$ is a non-negative random variable. [Therefore](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/897876/215011) it must equal zero almost surely, which implies $h(X)=E(Y\mid X)$ almost surely.

Comment: Thanks this is super well written and informative