# Ratio of expected values admits "intermediate value"?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let $X$ be a random variable with support $S$, let $f$ and $g$ be arbitrary positive functions of $X$. If
$$\frac{\mathbb E(f(X))}{\mathbb E(g(X))} = r$$
then is it true that there exists $x\in S$ such that
$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\le r$$
I think this is true, and can't come up with a counterexample, but I'm not sure how to show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true. It is a special case of the more general result:

> If $E[h(X)]=0$ then there exists $x$ such that $h(x)\le 0$.

Your claim corresponds to $h(x):=f(x)-rg(x)$. You can prove the general result via contrapositive: If $h(x)>0$ for every $x$ then $h(X)$ is a positive random variable, hence its expectation is not zero. (This conclusion follows from [the fact that](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/897876/215011) a nonnegative random variable with zero expectation must be zero almost surely.)

Comment: How is it a case of that? Doesn't your argument apply to $\mathbb E\left[\frac{f(X)}{g(X)}\right]$? The question is about $\frac{\mathbb E[f(X)]}{\mathbb E[g(X)]}$.

Comment: I see now – you're applying this to $h(X)=f(X)-rg(X)$? Perhaps you should make that explicit.

Comment: this makes sense, thanks for your help

Comment: @joriki  I added a note to make the connection explicit.