# Prove that if $E(X^2+Y^2) \lt \infty$, $E(X|Y)=Y$, $E(Y|X)=X$, then $P(X=Y)=1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

Suppose that X and Y are random variables on a common probability space such that $E(X^2+Y^2) \lt \infty$, $E(X|Y)=Y$, $E(Y|X)=X$. Prove that $$P(X=Y)=1$$

My work:
$E(X)=E(E(X|Y))=E(Y)$ and $E(Y)=E(E(Y|X))=E(X)$

But I don't know what to do next and I'm sure how to use the condition $E(X^2+Y^2) \lt \infty$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

We have the following,

\begin{align*}
E( (X-Y)^2   )&=  E(X^{2}+Y^{2}-2XY     )      \\
&=    E(X^{2}+Y^{2})-E(XY     )-E(XY     )       \\
&=    E(X^{2}     )+E(Y^{2}     )-E(E(XY |X    ))-E(E(XY  |Y   ))       \\
&=    E(X^{2}     )+E(Y^{2}     )-E(XE(Y |X    ))-E(YE(X |Y   ))       \\
&=    E(X^{2}     )+E(Y^{2}     )-E(X^2  )-E(Y^2   )       \\
&=0
\end{align*}
Therefore, $X=Y$ almost surely.

Comment: Intuitively it seems like we ought to be able to prove this with only EX and EY finite without worrying about the second moments.  Is there a coutnerexample?

Comment: @CMonsour The same holds when $X,Y \in L^{1}$.

Comment: $NYRAHHH it is hard to answer this in a comment since the proof is slightly longer. Why don't you ask a separate question?

Comment: For the proof without the $L_2$ inegrability, see e.g. this. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666843/if-exy-y-almost-surely-and-eyx-x-almost-surely-then-x-y-almost-surel