# For random variables $X,Y\in L^1$, if $E[X|\sigma(Y)]=Y$ and $E[Y|\sigma(X)]=X$, prove that $X=Y$ a.s.

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

> For random variables $X,Y\in L^1$, if $E[X|\sigma(Y)]=Y$ and $E[Y|\sigma(X)]=X$, prove that $X=Y$ a.s.

My attempt:

1. Note that $E[X-Y|\sigma(Y)]=E[X|\sigma(Y)]-E[Y|\sigma(Y)]=Y-Y=0$. Similarly, $E[X-Y|\sigma(X)]=0$.
2. By 1, if I could prove the following lemma, then $E[X-Y|\sigma(X,Y)]=X-Y=0$ as desired.

> **Lemma (not necessarily true).** If $E[Z|\mathcal A]=E[Z|\mathcal B]=0$ where $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ are two $\sigma$-fields, then $E[Z|\sigma(\mathcal A,\mathcal B)]=0$.

**Questions:**

1. Is this "lemma" correct? Is there a counterexample?
2. If not, how should I solve the original question?

Comment: I remember a theorem that if $E(Z_1 1_B)=E(Z_2 1_B)$ so almost sure $Z_1=Z_2$ (with a condition like $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are measurable with same sigma field, but i do not remember it exactly). In here $\forall B\in \sigma(X)$ $E(X1_B)=E(E(Y|X)1B)\overset{\star}{=}E(Y1_B)$ and $\forall B\in \sigma(Y)$ $E(Y1_B)=E(E(X|Y)1B)\overset{\star}{=}E(X1_B)$. ($\star$ is by definition of conditional expectation).Perhaps it will help

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/666843/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the lemma, it may unfortunately not work. Let $\varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon'$ be two i.i.d. random variables such that $\varepsilon$ takes the values $-1$ and $1$ with probability $1/2$. Let $Z=\varepsilon\cdot \varepsilon'$ and $\mathcal A=\sigma(\varepsilon)$, $\mathcal B=\sigma(\varepsilon')$. The random variable $Z$ is $(\mathcal A\vee\mathcal B)$-measurable and since $\varepsilon$ is $\mathcal A$-measurable, it follows that 
$$
\mathbb E\left[Z\mid\mathcal A\right]=\varepsilon\mathbb E\left[\varepsilon'\mid\sigma(\varepsilon)\right]=0
$$
and similarly, $
\mathbb E\left[Z\mid\mathcal A\right]=0$.

For the second question, it was solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666843/if-exy-y-almost-surely-and-eyx-x-almost-surely-then-x-y-almost-surel?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your lemma is true or not but for the original question, here is my idea

$E[(X-Y)Y]=E[E(X-Y)Y|\sigma(Y)]]=E[YE[X-Y|\sigma(Y)]]=0$

Similarly, $E(X-Y)X]=0$, combine these two equations, we get $E[(X-Y)^2]=0$, which gives the desire result.

Comment: I think the first line needs $X,Y\in L^2$. But the assumption only says they are $L^1$.

Comment: @trisct You’re right, maybe comment by JonathanHole will help.