# Conditional expectation: Prove $X_1 = X_2 \text{ a.s.}$

Tags: conditional-expectation

(This is a problem in chap 4 of 概率论教程（缪柏其 胡太忠著）. )

> Set space $(\Omega, \mathscr{A}, P)$, $\mathscr{C}_1, \mathscr{C}_2 \subset \mathscr{A}$, and $\mathscr{C}_1, \mathscr{C}_2$ are both $\sigma$ algebra, $X\in L_1, X_1=E[X|\mathscr{C}_1], X_2=E[X_1|\mathscr{C}_2]$. If $X=X_2, a.s.$, Prove $X_1=X_2, a.s.$.

I have thought about this for a few days, the point is to show that $X=E[X|\mathscr{C}_1], a.s.$, I have got the following result:

1. $\mathrm{E}\left[ |X_1| \right] =\mathrm{E}\left[ |X_2| \right],\ \mathrm{E}\left[ X_1 \right] =\mathrm{E}\left[ X_2 \right].  $
2. $\mathrm{E}\left[ |X||\mathscr{C} _1 \right] =|\mathrm{E}\left[ X|\mathscr{C} _1 \right] |,\ \mathrm{E}\left[ |X_1||\mathscr{C} _2 \right] =|\mathrm{E}\left[ X_1|\mathscr{C} _2 \right] |$.

I have read about two different answers, but I feel both of them have some bugs, however, it may provide some directions:

1. By the equation condition of Jensen inequality.
2. Try to show $X_1\ge c\,\,\Longleftrightarrow X\ge c,\ \forall c \in \mathbb{R} $.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I have  a proof using  a theorem from Functional Analysis. If no simpler proof appears by this time tomorrow I will post my proof.

Comment: @geetha290krm I have found methods we can use to solve this problem, check [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666843/if-exy-y-almost-surely-and-eyx-x-almost-surely-then-x-y-almost-surel?noredirect=1&lq=1), I will post the modified answer, but I still expect your proof!

Answer (score 3):

I have found two methods to solve this problem, these methods come from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666843/if-exy-y-almost-surely-and-eyx-x-almost-surely-then-x-y-almost-surel?noredirect=1&lq=1). We can simply modify these methods to solve the problem.

1. Let $h: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ to be a strictly increasing bounded continued function, then
   $$X_ih\left( X_j \right) \in L_1,\quad i,j=1,2.$$
   So
   $$\mathrm{E}\left[ \left( X_1-X_2 \right) \left( h\left( X_1 \right) -h\left( X_2 \right) \right) \right] 
   \\
   =\mathrm{E}\left[ X_1h\left( X_1 \right) \right] -\mathrm{E}\left[ X_2h\left( X_1 \right) \right] -\mathrm{E}\left[ X_1h\left( X_2 \right) \right] +\mathrm{E}\left[ X_2h\left( X_2 \right) \right] ,$$
   and since $X_1\in \mathscr{C} _1,\  X_2\in \mathscr{C} _2,$ we have
   $$
   \mathrm{E}\left[ X_2h\left( X_1 \right) \right] =\mathrm{E}\left[ \mathrm{E}\left[ X_2h\left( X_1 \right) |\mathscr{C} _1 \right] \right] 
   \\
   =\mathrm{E}\left[ h\left( X_1 \right) \mathrm{E}\left[ X_2|\mathscr{C} _1 \right] \right] 
   \\
   =\mathrm{E}\left[ h\left( X_1 \right) \mathrm{E}\left[ X|\mathscr{C} _1 \right] \right] 
   \\
   =\mathrm{E}\left[ X_1h\left( X_1 \right) \right],
   $$
   similarly, $\mathrm{E}\left[ X_1h\left( X_2 \right) \right] =\mathrm{E}\left[ X_2h\left( X_2 \right) \right] .$
   Thus,
   $$\mathrm{E}\left[ \left( X_1-X_2 \right) \left( h\left( X_1 \right) -h\left( X_2 \right) \right) \right] =0.$$
   So $\left( X_1-X_2 \right) \left( h\left( X_1 \right) -h\left( X_2 \right) \right) =0,\  \mathrm{a}.\mathrm{s}.$
   And since
   $$
   \left\{ \left( X_1-X_2 \right) \left( h\left( X_1 \right) -h\left( X_2 \right) \right) =0 \right\} \subset \left\{ X_1-X_2=0 \right\} ,
   $$
   we get $X_1=X_2,\ \mathrm{a}.\mathrm{s}.$.
2. $\forall a \in \mathbb{R},$ we have
   $$
   \mathrm{E}\left[ \left( X_1-X_2 \right) I_{\left\{ X_1\leqslant a \right\}} \right] 
   \\
   =\mathrm{E}\left[ X_1I_{\left\{ X_1\leqslant a \right\}} \right] -\mathrm{E}\left[ X_2I_{\left\{ X_1\leqslant a \right\}} \right] 
   \\
   =\mathrm{E}\left[ X_1I_{\left\{ X_1\leqslant a \right\}} \right] -\mathrm{E}\left[ \mathrm{E}\left[ X_2I_{\left\{ X_1\leqslant a \right\}}|\mathscr{C} _1 \right] \right] 
   \\
   =\mathrm{E}\left[ X_1I_{\left\{ X_1\leqslant a \right\}} \right] -\mathrm{E}\left[ X_1I_{\left\{ X_1\leqslant a \right\}} \right] =0.
   $$
   Also,
   $$
   \mathrm{E}\left[ \left( X_1-X_2 \right) I_{\left\{ X_1\leqslant a \right\}} \right] 
   \\
   =\mathrm{E}\left[ \left( X_1-X_2 \right) I_{\left\{ X_1\leqslant a,X_2>a \right\}} \right] +\mathrm{E}\left[ \left( X_1-X_2 \right) I_{\left\{ X_1\leqslant a,X_2\leqslant a \right\}} \right] = 0 ,
   $$
   since $\mathrm{E}\left[ \left( X_1-X_2 \right) I_{\left\{ X_1\leqslant a,X_2>a \right\}} \right] \leqslant 0$, we have $\mathrm{E}\left[ \left( X_2-X_1 \right) I_{\left\{ X_1\leqslant a,X_2\leqslant a \right\}} \right] \geqslant 0,$ which leads to $\mathrm{P}\left( X_1\leqslant a,X_2>a \right) =0.$
   This further leads to
   $$
   \mathrm{P}\left( X_2>X_1 \right) =\mathrm{P}\left( \bigcup_{a\in \mathbb{R}}{\left\{ X_1\leqslant a,X_2>a \right\}} \right) =0.
   $$
   Similarly, $\mathrm{P}\left( X_1>X_2 \right)=0$, thus $X_1=X_2,\   \mathrm{a}.\mathrm{s}.$

*Again these methods come from others, you can check the link to learn the original version.*

Comment: +1. The first proof is simple and elegant. I will not post my proof since you have an elementary proof.

Comment: When $EX^{2}<\infty$ we get a  very quick proof using FA: Conditional expectations are projection operators. If $P$ and $Q$ are projections on $M$ and $N$ then $(PQ)^{n}$ converges to the projection $R$ on $M \cap N$. This makes $X$ measurable w.r.t. both $\mathcal C_1$ and $\mathcal C_2$ (and all conditioning disappears)!